# Displaying Django model entries for logged in user in a profile page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-users, django-logging

I have two models. One is 'Task' and the other one is 'Entry' and I am able to see an overview of the all entries made for each task in Django Admin panel. I would like to create a similar page for logged in user to display which entries he created in db.

I tried to get them by using log data with LogEntry class, but I stucked at it. Does somebody know an efficient way to do it?

I have the following models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name="profile",
        verbose_name=_("user")
        )
    # Attributes - Mandatory
    interaction = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_("interaction")
        )
    inter_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Attributes - Optional
    # Object Manager
    objects = managers.ProfileManager()

    # Custom Properties
    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Profiles")
        ordering = ("user",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


#@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()

def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    user.profile.interaction += 1
    user.profile.save()

user_logged_in.connect(login_user)


class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    task_time = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.task_name

    # Object Manager
    #objects = managers.TaskManager()

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Task")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tasks")


class Entry(models.Model):
    select_task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="entries")
    entry_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    entry_date = models.DateField('Task performed date')
    publication_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.entry_quantity

    # Object Manager
    #objects = managers.EntryManager()

    # Meta and String
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Entry")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Entries")
```

This is what I have in Admin. I want to have something similar for each user (will show the entries made by that user only) in the user profile page. I had to cross over the tasks since the product doesn't belong to me.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to display user-submitted data in a Django view?

Comment: To make sure I'm clear, you can see Task and Entry in Django Admin, but you cannot see Profile and you want to?

Comment: I added a screenshot, I hope it describes better what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
# in admins.YourModelAdmin
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Entry)
    created_by_user = LogEntry.objects.filter(user=request.user, content_type = content_type).values_list('pk', flat = True)
    return qs.filter(pk__in=created_by_user)
```

May have to fiddle with some bits and bobs; but this should get you the `Entry` objects created by the currently logged in user.
For more information, please read [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) and [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).
If you want to include the user that has created a certain `Entry` in your changelist, refer to [list_disply](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have an `admin.py` in your app. That is where all of the Django Admin entries are defined. You likely have admin entries for `Tag` and `Entry` there. If you want one for `Profile`, add that there.

Comment: please see the added screenshot. I already have them listed in admin. Do you know a way to add the user who makes the entry to the admin view? With the similar logic, I can then filter it by user and try to figure out to list it similarly for active users in a profile page.

Comment: You'd need to track that on the model. Once you do that, you can modify the admin view to show that field in the list view (`list_display`).